# Add a group of checkbox so that multiple value can be stored in database

Tags: checkbox, moodle

I want to store multiple checkboxes value in the database , currently only last checkbox value  i.e. demo3 is stored.
Other values are not going in database .

```
    $preprocedure=array(); 
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure','', 'Demo1', array('group' => 1), array('','demo1'));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure','', 'Demo2', array('group' => 1), array('','demo2'));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure','', 'Demo3', array('group' => 1), array('','demo3'));
   $mform->addGroup($preprocedure, 'preprocedure', get_string('preprocedure', 'assignsubmission_metadata'),array('<br>'), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the name that you have used for the element which will only allow one value to be set at a time. If you want to store more than one value then you should use the name in array format.

Example one:

```
$preprocedure=array();
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure[demo1]','', 'Demo1', array('group' => 1), array('',1));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure[demo2]','', 'Demo2', array('group' => 1), array('',1));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure[demo3]','', 'Demo3', array('group' => 1), array('',1));
    $mform->addGroup($preprocedure, 'preprocedure', get_string('preprocedure', 'assignsubmission_metadata'),array('<br>'), false);
```

will give you:

```
object(stdClass)#181 (2) {
  ["preprocedure"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["demo1"]=>
           string(1) "1"
        ["demo2"]=>
           string(0) ""
        ["demo3"]=>
           string(1) "1"
}
 ["submitbutton"]=>
     string(12) "Save changes"
```

}

Example two:

```
$preprocedure=array();
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure[1]','', 'Demo1', array('group' => 1), array('','demo1'));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure[2]','', 'Demo2', array('group' => 1), array('','demo2'));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'preprocedure[3]','', 'Demo3', array('group' => 1), array('','demo3'));
    $mform->addGroup($preprocedure, 'preprocedure', get_string('preprocedure', 'assignsubmission_metadata'),array('<br>'), false);
```

Will give you:

```
object(stdClass)#181 (2) {
  ["preprocedure"]=>
      array(3) {
       [1]=>
         string(5) "demo1"
       [2]=>
         string(0) ""
       [3]=>
         string(5) "demo3"
     }
 ["submitbutton"]=>
     string(12) "Save changes"
```

}

Hope this helps.

Regards

Sandeep

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, i tried your code but now nothing is going in database .

Comment: Whenever i change name other than preprocedure it does not save anything

Comment: Sorry, I never got a notification for this. Were you able to resolve it?